# SL4, EF, Ria Services - When a deletion happens or doesn't happen on the Server Side, how does the Client Side know what happened?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

Using Bill Burrows Intro to SL4 and WCF Ria Services - Golf Example (http://www.myvbprof.com/MainSite/index.aspx#/zSL4_RIA_01), which I don't expect you to look at, but thought I'd add it as a great little tutorial for anyone looking to learn a bit about SL4 and WCF Ria Services with a VB.NET example.

The example uses a Client and Web setup.  The database has 2 tables, Courses and Scores.  You can create new Courses and then add Scores for that Course.  The database is setup to not allow you to delete Courses that have related Scores in the Scores table.  So, if you try to delete a Course that you've entered Scores for, you get an Entity Framework error.

**The DeleteCourse sub by default looks like this:**

```
Public Sub DeleteCourse(ByVal course As Course)
        If (course.EntityState = EntityState.Detached) Then
            Me.ObjectContext.Courses.Attach(course)
        End If
        Me.ObjectContext.Courses.DeleteObject(course)
End Sub
```

**I modified it to look like this by adding the call to a function, and adding the If/Then:**

```
Public Sub DeleteCourse(ByVal course As Course)
    Dim myCourseKeyValue As Integer = CheckForScores(course.CourseKey)

    If myCourseKeyValue = 0 Then
        If (course.EntityState = EntityState.Detached) Then
            Me.ObjectContext.Courses.Attach(course)
        End If
        Me.ObjectContext.Courses.DeleteObject(course)
    End If
End Sub
```

**So in the first line of the DeleteCourse Sub I'm calling a Function called CheckForScores that looks like this:**

```
Private Function CheckForScores(ByVal selectedCourseKey As Integer) As Integer
    Using dc As New Golf_DB1Entities
        Dim myScores = (From o In dc.Scores Where o.CourseKey = selectedCourseKey Select o).Count
        Return myScores
    End Using
End Function
```

So basically I'm calling the CheckForScores Function to see if any entries exist in the Scores Table for the selected Course.  This works fine, and I know there is probably an easier way to get this information, and I'm open to suggestions, but my actual question is, since this is a service being called from the client, once I figure out that there are Scores entries in the Scores Table for the Selected Course (from the server side), I don't delete the record from the database, but how does the client side of the SL4 application know that the deletion didn't actually take place?

I'm so sorry if this doesn't make any sense at all...

Also, is it OK that I tagged this question as VB.NET and C#???, even though it's technically a VB.NET question, I know that most SO users use C# and can probably read thru the VB.  If that's considered out of bounds, let me know so I don't make the same mistake again : ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a child table, and a parent table, and you don't delete the parent if there are any records in the child.  There are two possible options here.

One would be to just query twice, once to see if you can delete, and another time to actually delete.

Another option is to just call a Server Side Method.  You declare a server-side method using the [InvokeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.invokeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)  A server side method can have a return value, so your callback will be able to tell you if something was deleted or if it wasn't.  Google should have some examples of how to use this.